# Threejs Ply loader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I couldn't find a possible solution to add ambient, directional and point lights in a PLY object. I have got the ply file loading fine now, but it has a texture and I can not seem to get it to load, no matter how I configure things.

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: I am using this functionality with the help of cake php

Answer (score 1):

The three.js PLY loader only processes vertices, vertex colors and faces. If you want to support any other elements, you'll have to directly modify the source code of PLYLoader.js to support the features you need.

Strictly speaking, the elements you mention are all *non-standard* (i.e. PLY supports user-defined elements), so it's hardly surprising the default PLY loader doesn't support them.